# export tabular modell cube metadata?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I have several tabular cubes (.bim files) where I am trying to do some documentation.

I would like to find a way to automatically export for a given cube:

- Column name (cube level)
- Column name (source level)
- Table name (cube level)
- Table name (source level)
- Measure with corresponding dax code.

Is there a way I can get all these values with a single export, rather than building it myself by constantly copy pasting?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with installing SQLite 3 driver, setting it to point to metadata.sqlitedb from the instancename\OLAP\Data\DBName folder.
Then I have imported column, measure, etc. into the model as structured data source.

After refresh I can query all the data I need for documentation with DAX, can be saved manually with Dax Studio to excel or CSV, or automatically with Powershell SQLServer module to CSV.

Complicated first, but then, you have a self-documentating structure inside the model that can be refreshed when changed.
[Example selfdoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2N5D.png)

OR, if You are not afraid of some programming in C#,
create some classes for model/table/etc in JSON and read the bim file which is JSON with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);